# How to convert list of objects with two fields to array with one of them using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

It's hard for me to explain, so let me show it with pseudo code:

```
ObjectX
{
    int a;
    string b;
}
List<ObjectX> list = //some list of objectsX//
int [] array = list.Select(obj=>obj.a);
```

I want to fill an array of ints with ints from objectsX, using only one line of linq.

Comment: +1 `Lets talk using code`

Comment: thats why i love this job!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
int[] array = list.Select(obj=>obj.a).ToArray();
```

you need to just add `ToArray` at the end

Answer (score 5):

The only problem in your code is that [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `IEnumerable`.

Convert it to an array:
`int[] array = list.Select(obj=>obj.a).ToArray();`